# JavaScript runtime error: InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I'm getting an "Unhandled Exception" error at this specific point of the code:

```
{

function loadAccount(accountId) {
    // here->
    $("#accountDetails").load('/RxCard/GetAccount', { accountid: accountId }, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }

}
```

I have no idea what is causing this. I'm trying to run an application that will save the changes a user submits. The error appears as soon as I click on the "save" button. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing that error in the Javacript console or in the alert message?

Comment: Visual Studio is generating this message.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your $("#accountDetails").load with  });